# Rails Backup Gem fails to backup replicated PostgreSQL database on slave with pg_dump permission error

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

Running backup fails with the following error:

```
pg_dump: Error message from server: ERROR:  canceling statement due to conflict with recovery
DETAIL:  User query might have needed to see row versions that must be removed.
Errno::EPERM: Operation not permitted - 'pg_dump' returned exit code: 1
```

even though the user has permissions to access pg_dump on the database

This is a replicated database and the backup process is running on the slave.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make this work you have to enable

```
hot_standby_feedback = on
```

inside of

```
/etc/postgresql/SQL_VERSION/main/postgresql.conf
```

and then restart postgresql using

```
systemctl restart postgresql
```